# redirecting output of a command as if it was file input

Tags: pipe, io-redirection

I find myself always having to arrow up and going backwards through the command line to change one part of an earlier command that is pipped to a later `grep` or `head` or whatever command.

For a crude example: searching `dmesg` for a given string and only wanting the last 5 occurrences.

I would do the above such that:

```
dmesg | grep -i USB | tail -n 5
```

but then if I want to change the search term or what I am searching for or the source, I am waiting for my cursor to backtrace to the relevant part of the line. I'd like to move that to the end of the line such that the above example could be represented as (I know this is incorrect):

`tail -n 5 < dmesg | grep -i USB` (and I could then search for `sda`)

*as I said, this is a **crude** example and is indicative of the sort of thing I'd LIKE to do, but not actually what I want to do, ie. this isn't about `dmesg` or the use of `grep` and `tail`, but how to interact between these programs placing the "variable" at the end.*

This could be further exampled on getting the seek time on a DNS enquiry such that:

`dig google.com | grep msec` (let's move `google.com` to the end so that I can then test another domain) via
`grep msec < dig google.com`

*again, poor examples. I am talking more about when I have input/outputs flowing between multiple programs*

I do admit I only have a basic understanding of piping and redirection which could be summarised as:

- **piping (`|`)** using the `stdout` of one program to feed into the `stdin` of another
- **redirect (`>`)** taking the `stdout` of one program and feeding it into a file (*aside: could it be redirected elsewhere other than the only obvious ones I can think of*
  `> /dev/null`  *or*
  `> /dev/sda` *or*
  `> {said file}`
  whereas **piping** is program output as program input going left to right.
- **redirect (`<`)** *(which I call "file as input")* taking the contents of a file and using those as if they'd been typed at the command line

Comment: Are you talking about running the same command often, but with one part (not at the end) that varies? Or about editing the command you've just run to change one thing in the middle? Or something else? I can't work out what the general thing is that you're after, from your examples.

Comment: both of those really. It's usually as I'm trying to search for something or (as was recently the case) take two files sort them together on one field, pipe that thru grep, run a uniq on particular characters over that then sort that by a different field with a different delimiter, but then I'd want to change the grep term. In the end I solved that particular one by making a script file which took the grep term as an argument. Last nights example was similar but I'm testing a DNS and needed to keep changing the url (since it was now cached)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm often annoyed by the same thing, and there are a few ways of dealing with it:

1. Just accept it, sometimes it's not worth spending any time to work around it.
2. as PSkocik mentioned, you can use e.g. `tail -n 5 <(dmesg | grep USB)`
3. Become more adept with your shell's editing capabilities - e.g. in bash (and many other programs that use readline) you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to get to beginning of line, <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to move forward and back a "word", and <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-E</kbd> to edit the current line in $EDITOR (e.g. `vim`)

There are many more editing commands available and `readline` is fully documented in .info files.  On a Debian system, install the `readline-doc` package.  Other distros may include the documentation in the readline package itself or may separate it as Debian does.

I also recommend installing and using `pinfo` for a more lynx web-browser-like experience (IMO the GNU `info` browser is ghastly and almost unusable).  If it's not already in your distro, you can find it at http://pinfo.alioth.debian.org/

4. `readline` also has a `vi` mode for editing (the default is an `emacs`-like mode), which some people prefer.
5. In simple cases, you can use quick substitution:  e.g. if the last command you entered was:

`dmesg | grep -i USB | tail -n 5`

then typing <kbd>^USB^sda^</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> would result in this being executed:

`dmesg | grep -i sda | tail -n 5`

For more details on this, see `man bash` and search for `HISTORY EXPANSION`, especially the section `Event Designators`.

and yes, doing this repeatedly also becomes annoying.

6. For more complex cases, the best solution is to write a shell script or function that does what you want and run that instead of your long complicated pipeline of commands.

e.g.  write a shell script called `dmesg-grep` that looks something like this:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

# regexp to search for is arg 1.  needs to be an extended regexp
# because we're using grep -E aka egrep.
re="$1"

# number of lines to output is optional arg 2 (default 5)
lines=${2:5}

dmesg | grep -iE "$re" | tail -n "$lines"
```

Then you can just run `dmesg-grep usb` or `dmesg-grep sda`.

If you do this a lot, make a `bin` subdirectory of your home directory and add `~/bin` to your default PATH (e.g. in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`) and save your scripts in there.

Comment: I do think your first point is most apt! (deal with it lol). I knoew about CTRL+A, but not the ESC sequences. Thx. `#5` is PERFECT, again learning new things. Big thanks. I've done `#6` but that (your version) is even better. Although @PSkocik did come up with an acceptable answer first, I am going to go for this for it's completeness. Thanks very much :)

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention that `bash` also has `.info` documentation.  Depending on your distro, you might need to install `pinfo` and `bash-doc`  packages before you can run `pinfo bash`.  It has an entire chapter called Command Line Editing.  Also BTW, I use all of the above methods (except readline's `vi`-mode) at different times.

Answer (score 8):

In shell that support `<()` (bash, ksh, zsh), you can transform

```
$ cmd1 | cmd2
```

into

```
$ cmd2 < <(cmd1)
```

These two should be equivalent in terms of piping.
(However, I think there are some minor differences in terms of how the two forms handle things like process group and signals).

For better command line editing, I recommend you explore your shell's facilities for that.
E.g., bash has `set -o vi` which allows you to use vi-like shortcuts or switch into `vim` directly to edit your command more efficiently. The default `set -o emacs` uses emacs shortcuts (search `man bash` for readline to learn more about them (`/readline`)).

Comment: I was *so* close, I'd tried a double `<` but I had a space in there and then spaces within as well. As both you and `cas` have mentioned, I do think it's an example of learning my shell better (I use bash) with all default settings.

Comment: The other (inferior) way is by saving the output as a string and sending that string as the content of stdin to the next command, `cmd2 <<< "$(cmd1)"`.

Answer (score 1):

You may think this is a sideways answer, but often the solution is to simply use variables in your command line. They are not just for shell scripts. Eg you are developing a complex "one-liner" by trial-and-error and have:

```
 $ some complex command using value 23 at this point
```

then you want to vary just one value in the middle of the command line. A single edit and then the line becomes easy to recall without it needing any further editing:

```
 $ a=23
 $ some complex command using value "$a" at this point
 $ a=37
 $ some complex command using value "$a" at this point
 $ a=42
 $ some complex command using value "$a" at this point
```

It's even better when you need `$a` in 2 or more places in the command, such as for a directory or filename.

Comment: I have to admit, command line variables are not something that I've ever given a lot of thought to. I have experienced it playing with other command line "structures" including python and mysql, but have always viewed the command line as being "outside" that scope. Thanks for reminding me that that is not the case!